# How to create a table from grid data with independant axes

Tags: excel

I need to create a table (either pivot or normal) that combines data laid out in this grid:

[image: grid data]

The grid shows the count of items by their size, broken down by width on one axis and height on the other. I can't figure out a way to correlate the sizes with the data. The only way I have gotten it to work so far is by manually creating table rows one by one using formulas that reference each cell.

For example, the table should read like this:

| Size | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 X 3 | 0 |
| 3 X 4 | 0 |
| 3 X 6 | 20 |

I'm eventually going to use this table to create a Pareto chart, but if I can create the chart from this grid that would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get columns K and L below to show your distinct combinations, which shouldn't take more than several minutes, then the rest is pretty easy.

Column M is simply concatenating your results to show your data how you desire.

```
M2 formula: =CONCAT(K2, " x ", L2)
```

Then column N is using a formula against your data, referencing your values in columns K and L.

```
N2 formula: =INDEX($A$1:$H$8,MATCH(K2,$A$1:$H$1,0),MATCH(L2,$A$1:$A$8,0))
```

Drag 'em down and that's it.

[image]